# Reference type in Swift - reference to a function/closure

Tags: xcode, swift, reference, reference-type

I noticed that in Swift, when I create an **originalFunction()**  with a return value *returnValue*, and make a new function **let referenceA = originalFunction()**, this will happen:

1. Because **referenceA** is a reference to **originalFunction()**, when I do **let referenceB = referenceA** , **referenceB** and **referenceA** will share the *returnValue*.
2. But when I do **let referenceC = originalFunction()**, in which case I suppose **referenceC** and **referenceA** should also share the *returnValue* since they both refer to **originalFunction()**, this is not true.

Why?

Example:

```
func makeIncrementor(forIncrement amount:Int) -> () -> Int {    
    var runningTotal = 0     
    func incrementor() -> Int {    
        runningTotal += amount    
        return runningTotal    
    }    
    return incrementor    
}    

//then let's make referenceA    

let incrementByTen = makeIncrementor(forIncrement:10)    
incrementByTen()    
//returns 10    
incrementByTen()    
//returns 20    

//Now make referenceB    
let incrementBy10 = incrementByTen    
//referenceA and referenceB will share the *returnValue*:    
incrementBy10()    
//returns 30    

//Now make referenceC    
let incrementByTen10 = makeIncrementor(forIncrement:10)    
//referenceA and referenceC do not share the *returnValue*    
incrementByTen10()    
//returns 10
```

Answer (score 4):

Your `makeIncrementor` function creates a new `() -> Int` incrementor function that captures the `runningTotal` variable that you create right above it. Because closures are [reference types](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html) when you assign your `incrementByTen` closure to the new `incrementBy10` closure, you are really just assigning a reference and each of these `var`s are pointing to the same closure, so calling either of these will increment the same `runningTotal` `var` that the closure captured.

When you call `makeIncrementor` a second time, it creates a **new** closure that captures a new `runningTotal` `var`, so it does not share the same `runningTotal` with the first closure you created.

Your `incrementor` `func` is not shared because you declare it inside of `makeIncrementor`, so it is only alive for the scope of that calling of `makeIncrementor` and will be redeclared as a new `func` the next time `makeIncrementor` is called.  If you wanted this to be shared every time you called `makeIncrementor`, your `incrementor` `func` would need to be declared outside of `makeIncrementor`.

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is correct, this is because nested functions are a mere syntactic sugar to create closures, so another instance of `incrementor` is created every time `makeIncrementor` is called.

Your code above is nearly identical to this.

```
func makeIncrementor(forIncrement amount:Int) -> () -> Int {    
    var runningTotal = 0     
    let incrementor = {    
        runningTotal += amount    
        return runningTotal    
    }    
    return incrementor    
}
```